# How to get primary and secondary server name from a failovergroup name. Any C# code samples?

Tags: c#, azure, failover

I have a requirement to update (basically move database) from one failover group to another based on some logic.

Can someone help me with how to find primary and secondary SQL Server name from a failovergroup? Can someone confirm when we update failover, the second parameter in the `Update` method is the primary server name?

Do we have to update for secondary server as well or it will happen automatically via replication?

```
await client.FailoverGroups
            .UpdateAsync("resourcegroupname", "servername", "newfailovername", 
                         new FailoverGroupUpdate() { Databases = databases});
```

Comment: other details like failover group name, Failover group ID, Failover group location
, Failover group replication state, Failover group replication role, Failover group read-write endpoint, Failover group read-only, endpoint could also get [link](https://i.imgur.com/RZsP6gD.png)

Answer (score 1):

- Created SQl server and Configured Azure SQL Auto Failover [Groups](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7458/configure-azure-sql-failover-group/) .

[image]

[image]

- Register the application in Azure AD application and gave SQL Server Contributor role for the SQL Server.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;

namespace AzureSQLFailoverGroupInfo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tenantId = "72f988bf-86f1-41af-";
            string clientId = "fd6fbe88-d144-4c5c";
            string clientSecret = "3yj8Q~h_COxLnMrJ8";
            string subscriptionId = "b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a0";
            string resourceGroupName = "sampath";
            string serverName = "sampath23";
            string failoverGroupName = "sampath123";

            var serviceClientCredentials = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret).Result;

            SqlManagementClient sqlClient = new SqlManagementClient(serviceClientCredentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            };

            FailoverGroup failoverGroup = sqlClient.FailoverGroups.Get(resourceGroupName, serverName, failoverGroupName);

            string secondaryServer = failoverGroup.PartnerServers[0].Id.Split('/')[8];
       

            Console.WriteLine($"Secondary Server: {secondaryServer}");

            string FailoverGroupName = failoverGroup.Name;

            Console.WriteLine($"failure Server name : {FailoverGroupName}");
          
        }
    }
}
```

- The primary server name will be Azure SQL server name.

[image]